# Italicize text (genus/species) within endnote title causes compilation to fail

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, italic, endnotes

I would like to italicize *Homo sapiens* in a cited reference in my endnotes. Unitalicized works fine. Add \textit{} and compilation fails.

Minimal not-working test.bib:

```
@online{sib_swiss_institute_of_bioinformatics_q8wz42_nodate,
    title = {Q8WZ42 ({TITIN}\_HUMAN) \textit{Homo sapiens} (Human)},
    url = {https://swissmodel.expasy.org/repository/uniprot/Q8WZ42},
    author = {{SIB Swiss Institute of Bioinformatics}},
    urldate = {2024-01-04},
}
```

This works fine if \textit{} isn't used in the reference title field:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    
\usepackage[notes,notetype=endonly,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{endnotes}
    
\addbibresource{test.bib}
    
\begin{document}
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor\autocite{sib_swiss_institute_of_bioinformatics_q8wz42_nodate}
    
    \theendnotes
        
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `enotez`, but the problem is the same; a workaround is available,

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@online{sib_swiss_institute_of_bioinformatics_q8wz42_nodate,
    title = {Q8WZ42 ({TITIN}\_HUMAN) \textit{Homo sapiens} (Human)},
    url = {https://swissmodel.expasy.org/repository/uniprot/Q8WZ42},
    author = {{SIB Swiss Institute of Bioinformatics}},
    urldate = {2024-01-04},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    
\usepackage[
  notes,
  notetype=endonly,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  url=false,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{enotez}
    
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewCommandCopy{\latextextit}{\textit}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\textit}{m}{\latextextit{#1}}

\begin{document}
    
Lorem ipsum dolor\autocite{sib_swiss_institute_of_bioinformatics_q8wz42_nodate}
    
\printendnotes
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

But also `endnotes` sort of works.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@online{sib_swiss_institute_of_bioinformatics_q8wz42_nodate,
    title = {Q8WZ42 ({TITIN}\_HUMAN) \textit{Homo sapiens} (Human)},
    url = {https://swissmodel.expasy.org/repository/uniprot/Q8WZ42},
    author = {{SIB Swiss Institute of Bioinformatics}},
    urldate = {2024-01-04},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    
\usepackage[
  notes,
  notetype=endonly,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  url=false,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{endnotes}
    
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewCommandCopy{\latextextit}{\textit}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\textit}{m}{\latextextit{#1}}

\begin{document}
    
Lorem ipsum dolor\autocite{sib_swiss_institute_of_bioinformatics_q8wz42_nodate}
    
\theendnotes
        
\end{document}
```

However, I always get

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                paulend
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Works perfectly, and at least for me without the warning you mentioned. Appreciate the note re: enotez; I did try it but is incompatible with some of my other packages